# rails + sqlite - Can't remove columns from database due to foreign key issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm currently unable to delete a column from a specific table in my database. the error message sqlite3 gives me is:

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE 'table_name'

I am not trying to drop a table though, my migration is

```
remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```

This is just a string data column, nothing special about it

Comment: Probably you have a table referencing that column_name as foreign_key?

Comment: SQLite has no DROP COLUMN statement, so the migration must be implemented by creating a different table.

Comment: @CL. Makes sense. I wasn't aware of that limitation, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to a limitation in older versions of SQLite. Rails 5 uses a workaround that duplicates the table without the columns to remove, drops the original table, and then renames the duplicated table. But it fails if there are records with foreign keys.

You can either update the SQLite to the latest version or use this patch: https://gist.github.com/javier-menendez/3cfa71452229f8125865a3247fa03d51

Answer (score -1):

I did `ruby db:migrate:redo` and it worked.