# Can't rollback migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, migration

I created migration:

```
class AddVisibleToStocks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :stocks, :visible, :boolean
  end
end
```

I migrated it. Everything was ok, but when I needed to rollback it I seen error:

```
rake db:rollback

== 20180404150630 AddVisibleToStocks: reverting ===============================
-- remove_column(:stocks, :visible, :boolean)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::ConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed: DROP TABLE "stocks"
```

My Stock model:

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :providers
end
```

Then I made another migration and immediately rolled it back - the result is the same.

What's wrong?

Comment: please share code present in `Stock` model.

Comment: ok, I shared code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support removing existing columns, so it's probably implemented by creating a new table with all the existing columns but the one being removed. The the old table is dropped and this causes the error.

I'd suggest to use some other database (I recommend postgres), SQLite is not suitable to use on production anyway.

See also:

- [rails + sqlite - Can't remove columns from database due to foreign key issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44894376/580346)
- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html